# Partial date search on Date Of Birth Fields in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have one field which is dateofbirth whose mapping is something like below
"dateofbirth" : {
"type" : "date",
"fields" : {
"tokens" : {
"type" : "text"
}
},
"ignore_malformed" : true,
"format" : "yyyy-MM-dd"
},
I have a use case where i need to search on the basis of yyyydd & yyyy & yyyyMM, Does any one know how to apply analyzer in such case, so that tokens can be created for searching.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to  resolve above.

1. Create additional fields for year, month and day

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "dateofbirth": {
        "type": "date",
        "fields": {
          "tokens": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        },
        "ignore_malformed": true,
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
      "year":{
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "month":{
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "day":{
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can query it using multiple term clauses based on format you need

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "year": {
              "value": "VALUE"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "month": {
              "value": "VALUE"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

2. Using range query.
   For yyyydd

```
{
   "query": {
     "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
           "range": {
             "dateofbirth": {
               "gte": "2019-01-05",
               "lte": "2019-12-31"
             }
           }
          }
        ]
     }
   }
}
```

For year range will 2019-01-01 & 2019-12-31 ., for yyyyMM range will 2019-10-01 and 2019-10-31

3. Using script

```
{
   "query": {
     "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "script": {
              "script": {
                "source": "int year = doc['dateofbirth'].value.getYear();int month = doc['dateofbirth'].value.getMonthValue();int day = doc['dateofbirth'].value.getDayOfMonth(); if(year==params.year && month==params.month) return true;",
                "params": {
                  "year":2019,
                "month":10
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
     }
   }
}
```

Option 1 will have highest performance followed by 2 and 3.